# Licensing game in BGE

Tags: game-engine

I am making a new blender game, but I wanted to find out about license. I want to know how to get license, and how I can sell my game for money. Do I have to pay royalties?

P.S. When you put it on hold, I was very disappointed; because, where else can I ask question about blender? This is not question asked very much- I just asked how to license a game!

Comment: READ:http://www.blender.org/support/faq/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal/licensing issues.

Comment: how Blender/BGE can legally be used is directly related to Blender.

Comment: @MarcClintDion It is directly related to blender, but we can't deal with legal issues. See: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/422/are-licensing-questions-off-topic

Comment: That why I posted what Ton wrote.

Comment: Then again, this page does have great potential for turning into a flame war due to the type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ton just updated the following page but he did fail to mention anything about whether money can be made off BGE games.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Licensing

> Licensing of Blender Games
>
> Blender and the Blender Game Engine (BGE) is licensed as GNU GPL,
>   which means that your games (if they include Blender software) have to
>   comply with that license as well. This only applies to the software,
>   or the bundle if it has software in it, not to the artwork you make
>   with Blender. All your Blender creations are your sole property.
>
> GNU GPL - also called "Free Software" - is a license that aims at
>   keeping the licensed software free, forever. GNU GPL does not allow
>   you to add new restrictions or limitations on the software you
>   received under that license. That works fine if you want your clients
>   or your audience to have the same rights as you have (with Blender).
>
> For people who prefer to lockup software or to restrict distribution
>   or copying of their games, the BGE is not a good choice. The best they
>   can achieve is to separate the contents (.blend files with game
>   design) from the software (BGE) in their distribution, and license the
>   first under own copyrights and keep the latter as GNU GPL. Standalone
>   games
>
> In case you save out your game as a single "Standalone" the .blend
>   file gets included in the binary (the BGE player). That requires the
>   .blend file to be compatible with the GNU GPL license.
>
> In this case, you could decide to load and run another .blend file
>   game (using the Game Actuator logic brick). That file then is not part
>   of the binary, so you can apply any license you wish on it. More info
>
> More information you can find in the blender.org FAQ:
>   http://www.blender.org/support/faq/
>
> (Disclaimer: the former text on this page was inaccurate and had wrong
>   statements in it. The current text has been rewritten by Blender
>   Foundation's chairman. If you have questions about GPL, consult the
>   Free Software Foundation website fsf.org.

Comment: I read that but I don''t understand it

Comment: @AdriansNetlis Does this help https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-general-public-license-v3-%28gpl-3%29 ?

Comment: @stacker I need to find out how do I get my own license so I can sell my game...

Comment: I see where the confusion is coming from now.  You are thinking of the GNU-GPL license as if it's the same thing you would purchase from a commercial company in order to use their software.  Unfortunately the same word is being used for two different things.  You cannot purchase the right to use Blender Game Engine, you already have it.  The GNU-GPL license jibber-jabber is not really a license in that sense of the word.  It's an agreement not a purchase.  You cannot re-define those rules and choose to make your game a commercial closed-source project.  It's public property.

Comment: @AdriansNetlis For commercial use you should consider to switch to an engine like Unity.

Comment: Unreal Engine 4 is also a good choice.  It's $20.00 with source code included.  It even says on the license agreement page that you still can use the software and keep the source code after you cancel your subscription. You can renew your subscription for an additional $20.00 if and when you choose to upgrade. The only real obligation is the 5% royalties for any games that bring in more than 12,000 a year.

Comment: Can i use GNU to sell my game?

Comment: @AdriansNetlis You *can* sell under GNU, but anyone that buys it can redistribute it for free, its their right and cannot be changed.

Comment: Oh... So they can do something like sell it further?